# Reference Excel sheet number in an external workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook and in that workbook I would like to make a reference to the external Workbook "Book4"

[image: Book4]

When I write:

```
Text = Workbooks("Book4").Worksheets("Text").Range("A2").Value
```

It works. However I would like to make the reference not by using the actual sheet name “Text” but the CodeName (Sheet1).

But when I write below code, which I would expect should have done the trick, it doesn’t seem to work

```
Text = Workbooks("Book4").Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
```

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but just change `"Text"` to the name of the sheet you want, which looks like that is `"Sheet1"` - It can be a variable instead of a literal string. The way you do it does not work because the CODE name `Sheet1` already knows which workbook it's in, so you don't qualify it, and it will not be variable then either.

Comment: `Dim s As String` - `s = "Text"` - `Workbooks("Book4").Worksheets(s).Range("A2").Value`

Comment: Thank you for your reply braX. The problem is that "Text" is the actual sheet name. So if I in my code refer to Worksheets("Text") the code will only holds true if the Worksheet remains named "Text". However if the code instead refers to the sheet number (Sheet1) I can then change the sheet name from "Text" to "Text2" and the code will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for this:

```
Function SheetByCodeName(wb As Workbook, cn As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName = cn Then
            Set SheetByCodeName = ws
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Set SheetByCodeName = Nothing
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
Debug.Print SheetByCodeName( ThisWorkbook, "Sheet1" ).Name
```

Comment: But as I understand, you want to refer to it as `Sheet1`, its `CodeName` according to the picture.

Comment: `Text` is the `Name` of the sheet in your examplex, and `Sheet1` is not the sheet number, its the `CodeName` of the sheet. If you use a number as index, like `1`, then the sheet will be selected based on its visual position, e.g. if you drag a sheet with the mouse, its number will change.

Comment: I did not know that it was referred to as the sheet CodeName I though it was referred to as sheet number. But you are correct, it is the code name of the sheet I would like to reference.

Comment: There is no simpler solution. I have been using this for decades. VBA does not change.

Comment: So you mean that if I make references in the current workbook I can type: Sheet1.Range("A2").Value but if I would like to make the reference for an external workbook, Workbooks("Book4").Sheet1.Range("A2").Value there are no "simple" solution?

Comment: @jqx204s: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @jqx204s You may have misunderstood how you would use the function: `Text = SheetByCodeName(Workbooks("Book4"), "Sheet1").Range("A2").Value`.

Answer (score 0):

VBA code recognizes as objects the CodeNames of the actual book... So the "Text = Workbooks("Book4").Sheet1.Range("A2").Value"  must be done by generating equivalent code:

in a module:

```
Public Function getWbook(wbName As String) As Workbook
    Dim w As Workbook
    
    For Each w In Workbooks
        If w.Name = wbName Then
            Set getWbook = w
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Set w = Nothing
End Function

'Public Function getSheetOfCodeName(wb As Workbook, codeName As String) As Worksheet
'    Dim sh As Worksheet
'    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
'        If sh.codeName = codeName Then
'            Set getSheetOfCodeName = sh
'            Exit Function
'        End If
'    Next
'End Function

Public Function getCellValue(wb As Workbook, codeName As String, sRange As String) As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        If sh.codeName = codeName Then
            getCellValue = sh.Range(sRange).Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function


Private Sub example()
    'The "SHEETA" is the CodeName of the sheet...
    Debug.Print getCellValue(getWbook("test-31.xlsm"), "SHEETA", "A1")
End Sub
```

and finally a version to use as formula in cells:

```
Public Function getCellValueFormula(wbookName As String, sheetCodeName As String, sRange As String) As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Set wb = getWbook(wbookName)
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        If sh.codeName = sheetCodeName Then
            getCellValueFormula = sh.Range(sRange).Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```